# Best strategy for tuning a 4 piece kit?

Tags: tuning, drums, drum-kits

I recently got an acoustic kit after playing an electric kit for a while. There's a lot to learn, but one thing that I keep getting hung up on is how to tune my kit.

I've read a bunch of guides, and definitely watched enough youtube videos – but I can't figure out how to organize this. I don't know much about music theory, but is there something I'm missing here? Or am I just over thinking it?

I picked up a Tunebot to try and help narrow things down, but I think my issue is more fundamental. Here is how I have everything tuned now, but I think both the rack/floor tom are too low (and the kick never seems quite right):

[image: Drum kit labeled with how they are tuned.]

#### Update for more context

[Todd Wilcox](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/6070/todd-wilcox) asked for some more context on how I ended up with this tuning. After reading all these answers it's pretty clear that the snare/kick don't matter as much – but for the toms I followed the [Tunebot guide](https://tune-bot.com/tunebottuningguide.pdf#page=2):

[image: Tunebot guide]

I started with **2A** & **2D** for the toms, and it sounded only OK. Then I realized my rack tom is 13" and not 12", so I thought the lower tuning (**2F** & **2C#**) would be a better fit for this kit.

I had a feeling this would end up being very subjective, but I have definitely learned a lot reading all the responses

Comment: What will you do, whenever a song changes key? Retune each time? // As Edward pointed out, harmony is not a vital concept for drums, while sound is. Better make each sound characteristic, so we hear „oh, that‘s a different drum“. Consider (non-)resonant tuning, e.g. metallic sound for snare, and dampening, e.g. with some tissue. // Tuning may be relevant to give room to the bass playerin the low frequencies: don‘t overplay them. // For inspiration see this fun video from Benny Greb: https://vid.puffyan.us/watch?v=J0pKWox-j5Q

Comment: Can you edit to explain how you arrived at the pitches you are currently tuning to? Are they semi-random/just what sounds good or did you go through a process to determine the most resonant pitches of your shells?

Answer (score 7):

Warning: This is probably subjective.

The actual note pitch of your snare doesn't matter that much, it's more just a measure of how high or low it is.  I tune my snare to G, roughly, I think that's a good middle ground for rock music.

The actual note pitch of the kick only matters if you let it ring out to make a clear pitch.  For the typical rock kick sound, it doesn't matter.  I don't know what note my kick is.  I like kicks tuned to thud, or perhaps thump.

For the toms, the actual pitch doesn't matter that much either, only that they sound the right distance apart (usually about a 4th) and that they sound good together (usually means tuning them a 4th or 5th apart).  So on that note, raise your rack tom to F# or G#.  If you are tuning your kick to a note (as above) then your toms should sound good with the kick too- probably a fifth apart.

Beyond that, you could open a new question for how to tune each drum individually to achieve your target pitch, and you will get basically every possible way as an answer.  That part is extremely subjective, so I think the most sensible approach is:

Watch a youtube video on how to tune x drum (snare, kick, or both toms)

If you like the sound in the video, tune your drum like that.  Else, find another video.

Play your drums like that for a day or 2, to learn how the tuning sounds and feels in person.

Repeat.

Decide which tuning scheme you liked best.

Remember, if you're using hearing protection, like you should, then that affects how your drums sound.  Your drums will also sound different to you sitting behind the kit vs someone elsewhere in the room.  Recording your drums gives you more ways to hear them.

Answer (score 4):

Having both batter and resonant heads the same is probably more important.

BUT - having said that, my kick is filled with a duvet (down and feather, of course!), so there is no ring about it. Having a ringing bass drum doesn't work for most pieces of music - particularly pop/rock/blues, as it resonates for too long, and often whatever note will clash with what the bassist is playing. Even tuned to a 'good' note, it would still clash a lot of the time. Hence, dull thud, no discernible pitch.

Snare likewise. No, not a duvet, but care to keep it away from a pitch at which it will ring sympathetically. Nothing more annoying at a recording session than that happening whenever a particular pitch gets played by someone else! That apart, the actual tuning pitch becomes somewhat obscured when the snare is on, although it can be detected with it off.

Toms - often there are three - two kick drum mounted, and a floor tom (or even two). It is possible to tune them so they work with a song, and that's been done plenty of times. Trouble is, it'll only work for one key. So generally speaking, they're tuned a 4th, or 5th apart - here, both heads in tune works well. Whatever note may be down to the size of each drum, and obviously the higher each pitch, the tighter the skin. More important a factor for the batter head, and what tension the drummer prefers.

So, no hard and fast rules. I often hear drummers tweaking the tuning before a gig, but never hear them ask for an A, for a B♭! More important, it seems, to just get  them  resonating, and relative to each other, given the time.

Answer (score 4):

In 40 years [on & off] of being a drummer, I've always considered this task to be…

… an entire day of tuning, changing your mind until you're just about happy. You then follow this with a gig or session during which you invariably hate what you've done & determine to do it again tomorrow.
You follow this with several weeks of 'mañana'/procrastination/inertia… then rinse & repeat until unhappy.

You later listen back to some of those sessions & think.. "Dammit, I like that. How did I do it?"
Gigs, of course, don't count - because you never ever heard what the audience heard.

You could try "The Drum Tuning Bible" which is a much-quoted & oft-linked resource, easily googleble & linked from a myriad mirrors, including https://www.stevesuchdrums.com/stevesuchblog/drumtuningbible
which is a reference I often read during periods of ennui between tuning binges. I can't say I've ever really followed it, but I always have it in mind every time  I re-tune the kit.

It comes down to patience, your ears, patience, willingness to try many similar structures, and did I mention patience…

You can go through tricks to increase then reduce resonance; whether you like the bottom skin higher or lower pitch [makes the note rise or fall after strike]; dropping one corner once you find the 'ring point'; extreme use of damping vs one weeny bit of tape in a corner…  Kick full of duvet or let it ring then tune-damp it.
Every day is a new tuning experience, dampened [pardon the pun] only by enthusiasm, or lack thereof.

*There is no definitive answer to this question, only experimentation & experience.*

Comment: I've upvoted this and also suggest it might be best to quote some of the most important bits of the The Drum Tuning Bible to make it a complete answer.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I'd love to… but it's 20 pages of very dry, concise text. There isn't really anything you could lift out & hold up as an example. It's not a resource that's going to suffer link rot [or if this specific link rots, Google can find many others.] It's been kicking round the interwebz for over 20 years & is mirrored in many places.

Comment: Yeah I’ve read it and used it before - going back to when it was new.

Comment: Would upvote this twice if possible.  I played drums for 30 years (10 or so seriously, the rest "off and on") and it never once occurred to me to tune the resonant lower or higher than the batter to affect the pitch of the decay.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a definitive answer on this some time ago and found information that includes much of what is being said here.

Here are two links to the same website that have videos and documentation on how to tune for different types of drumkits.

The rock and fusion kits show tuning for 5-piece kits.  You should be able to get good sounds from a 4-piece by omitting the larger rack tom from your tuning.

All this information is good no doubt.  I personally tune by ear.  I tend to like deeper notes than what is shown here.

Hopefully this helps.  Enjoy.

[Sticks and Staves tuning website](http://www.sticksandstaves.com/index.php?id=44)

[Sticks and Staves PDF document on note tuning for different styles of acoustic
drums sets](http://www.sticksandstaves.com/content/Drumkit%20Tuning.pdf)

Comment: Pure references will eventually suffer from rot, so this won't be much use then.

Answer (score -1):

You are over thinking it. The physics of drums is fundamentally different from  "musical" instruments which have a Fundamental frequency and harmonics that are integer multiples the Fundamental. The relationship between the fundamental and the harmonics is what allows objective tuning of "musical" instruments.

Circles (like a drum head) don't have this property, and can't be tuned to a note, the shape simply does not allow it, and if you hit the drum in a different place on the drum head you will get a different sound.

Comment: Try telling that to Drums Workshop, who will stamp the resonant frequency of their shells inside in case a drummer wants to tune the heads to approximately that note. Even if the overtones of a drum head are inharmonic, that doesn't mean there is no fundamental (or perhaps a better word is "lowest") frequency for a tuned drum. If the heads are tuned to the strongest resonant frequency of the shell, then the drum will be the loudest and most responsive it can be, and have the longest sustain.